# what type of big o notation is this algorithm? I need help double checking

Tags: big-o

can someone tell me what type of o notation this algorithm is, i think its O(n^2) but i want to make sure im getting this right

```
function uniqueQuadratic(words) {
  const unique = [];                //  *  = O(?)
  for (
    let i = 0;                      //  *  = O(?)
    i < words.length;               //  *  = O(?)
    i++                             //  *  = O(?)
  ) {
    const word = words[i];          //  *  = O(?)
    let isUnique = true;            //  *  = O(?)
    for (
      let c = 0;                    //  *  = O(?)
      c < i;                        //  *  = O(?)
      c++                           //  *  = O(?)
    ) {
      const comparing = words[c];   //  *  = O(?)
      if (comparing === word) {     //  *  = O(?)
        isUnique = false;           //  *  = O(?)
      }
    }
    if (isUnique) {                 //  *  = O(?)
      unique[unique.length] = word; //  *  = O(?)
    }
  }
  return unique;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it’s O(n^2) because it has an outer loop that iterates n times and an inner loop that also iterates n times, resulting in n * n iterations. The O(n^2) notation is an algorithm whose time complexity is directly proportional to the square of the size of the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
function uniqueQuadratic(words) {
  const unique = [];                //  *  = O(1)
  for (
    let i = 0;                      //  *  
    i < words.length;               //  *  
    i++                             //  *  = O(words.lengh)
  ) {
    const word = words[i];          //  *  = O(1)
    let isUnique = true;            //  *  = O(1)
    for (
      let c = 0;                    //  * 
      c < i;                        //  *  
      c++                           //  *  = O(words.length)
    ) {
      const comparing = words[c];   //  *  = O(1)
      if (comparing === word) {     //  *  = O(1)
        isUnique = false;           //  *  = O(1)
      }
    }
    if (isUnique) {                 //  *  = O(1)
      unique[unique.length] = word; //  *  = O(1)
    }
  }
  return unique;
```

Result O(n2) where n = words.length